# What is an iPhone 4,1?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have developed an iOS app, and I am using a service called TestFlight to distribute the application to some beta testers.

Here is an image of the service:

[image]

What is an iPhone4,1?

If it is referring to a normal iPhone 4, I suppose it wouldn't include the ,1 there. So what is this? Perhaps some model number?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### iPhone4,1 = iPhone 4s

---

Full list:

```
╔═══════════════╦═══════════╗  
║ iPhone        ║ iPhone1,1 ║
║ iPhone 3G     ║ iPhone1,2 ║
║ iPhone 3Gs    ║ iPhone2,1 ║
║ iPhone 4      ║ iPhone3,1 ║
║ iPhone 4s     ║ iPhone4,1 ║
║ iPhone 5 GSM  ║ iPhone5,1 ║
║ iPhone 5 CDMA ║ iPhone5,2 ║
║ iPhone 5c     ║ iPhone5,3 ║
║ iPhone 5s     ║ iPhone6,1 ║
║ iPhone 6      ║ iPhone7,2 ║
║ iPhone 6 Plus ║ iPhone7,1 ║
╚═══════════════╩═══════════╝
```

Comment: Just call it 4S goddammit Apple.

Comment: Is there a good reason why a 4 is a 3,1 and so on?

Comment: One of the side effects is that developers can use it to identify architectural differences. For example, >= 6,0 is 64 bit (therefore 5c = 5,3 and 5s = 6,1).

Comment: The differences with the 'major version' of the iPhone is that they represent different processor characteristics. The iPhone and iPhone 3G shared the same processor (ARM 11) whereas the iPhone 3Gs used a new one (Cortex A8). These affect the type of programs that get compiled, whether they use thumb instructions and so on.  Note that the various iPhone 5 devices (original and 5c) use the same Apple A6 but that the iPhone 5s uses an Apple A7. The minor variations show small differences e.g. to distinguish a 5 GSM and CDMA or between those and the 5c.